# block mac address with Iptables during attack

Tags: linux, networking, security, iptables, mac-address

I have to setup Iptables to block every mac address from which 10 requests come in one minute. (ssh or http login)

To block the IP is achievable with

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-above  10/minute -j DROP
```

To block a known mac address is achievable with

```
iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source 00:00:00:00:00:00 -j DROP
```

But how to do this if the mac address is unknown?

Maybe with `arp -a`  command ?

How to combine `iptables` and `arp`?

Is there a smarter way?

**EDIT:**

Operating mode *CLIENT*
The attacked is connected to a wifi subnet, the attacker could be connected to the same subnet

Operating mode *Hotspot*
The attacked acts as a hotspot, generating its own wifi subnet to which the attacker could connect.

Comment: If you don't know the MAC address, then you cannot block it.  You are aware that most operating systems support randomization of MAC addresses right? Blacklists don't really work.

Comment: Are your clients on the same subnet as you? Attempting to block an attacker who's in a different subnet would end up blocking your own gateway...

Comment: Looks like an XY question to mee. If the attacker is in your own subnet, then you should seriously consider other measures to limit access to your own subnet.

Comment: Actually, all the comments say the right things. Unfortunately I have requirements to meet. I am only a developer, someone else decides the requirements. 
However, I must add some information that I initially left out.
Not only the attacker could be in the same sub-network as the attacked (and this is another problem), while the attacked is operating as a network client.
But during a certain mode of operation, the attacked may act as a hotspot, generating its own wifi subnet to which the attacker could connect.

Comment: Usually this is done based on destination port or IP, not MACs because they're easily changeable - so are IPs, which is why ports are often used.

Answer (score 0):

You are going about this the wrong way, as others have said blocking based on MAC address isn't going to work.

Instead you should use fail2ban and ipset

Another approach could be:

The set MUST exist before you load the iptables entry.

```
ipset create ban hash:net
```

This drops packets already on the ban list

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set ban src -j DROP
```

This adds IPs to the ban list.

```
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p tcp --dport 22 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-above  10/minute -j SET --add-set ban src
```

Comment: Thanks for help, I will try this

Answer (score 0):

In general, port `22` *(same with `1194`)* should never be exposed to WAN due to this very reason, as it receives thousands of connection attempts daily, which are auto-blocked by all firewalls unless `22` is exposed to WAN *(use a much higher port in the tens of thousands, as port scanners don't usually scan all 65,535 ports)*.

There are a multitude of ways to block traffic via rate limiting with only [`iptables`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html):

- MAC filtering is never effective as MACs are dynamic and changed with ease
- IP filtering is better, but can be changed via a VPN
- Port filtering is often the best and most effective:

  ```bash
  # Establish Zone: Port_Log
    iptables  -N  Port_Log

  # Establish rule for traffic on port 22 for Zone: Port_Log
    iptables  -A  Port_Log      -p  tcp   --dport     22          -m  limit       --limit 3/min     --limit-burst   3     -j  REJECT
    iptables  -A  Port_Log                                                                                                -j  DROP
    # Integrated into firewall.user script below:
      ## $PL $tcp $SSH $limit3 -j REJECT

  # Establish rule for new incoming traffic on port 22 for Zone: INPUT
    iptables  -I  INPUT         -p  tcp   --dport     22          -m  conntrack   --ctstate NEW                           -j  REJECT
    # Integrated into firewall.user script below:
      ## $IN $tcp $SSH $New -j REJECT
  ```
- Default base `iptables` script I start with on OpenWrt [`/etc/firewall.user`]:

  ```bash
  #

          ##::[[---  OpenWrt Firewall Script  ---]]::##

  #===========================================================
                    ##----- IPtables -----##
  #===========================================================


      # Paramaters #
  #-----------------------------------------------------------

  # Chains:
    IN="iptables  -I  INPUT"
    PL="iptables  -A  Port_Log"

  # Limit:
    limit3="-m  limit   --limit 3/min     --limit-burst   3"
    limit4="-m  limit   --limit 4/sec"
    New="-m  conntrack   --ctstate NEW"

  # Ports:
    echR="--icmp-type echo-request"
    SSH="--dport     22"


  # Protocols:
    icmp="-p  ICMP"
    tcp="-p  tcp"
    udp="-p  udp"


      # Establish Custom Zones #
  #-----------------------------------------------------------

  # Limit:
    iptables  -N  Port_Log


      # Establish Rate Limit #
  #-----------------------------------------------------------
  # ICMP:
    $PL      $icmp  $echR         $limit4     -j  ACCEPT

  # SSH:
    $PL      $tcp   $SSH          $limit3     -j  REJECT

  # Default:
    $PL      $tcp                             -j  REJECT    --reject-with   tcp-reset
    $PL      $udp                             -j  REJECT    --reject-with   icmp-port-unreachable
    $PL    ! $icmp                            -j  LOG       --log-prefix    "<[[--- Connection DROPPED ---]]> : "
    $PL                                       -j  DROP


      # Apply Rate Limit #
  #-----------------------------------------------------------

  # ICMP:
    $IN      $icmp                            -j  Port_Log

  # SSH:
    $IN      $tcp   $SSH          $New        -j  REJECT
  ```